# Firebase messaging. iOS app not receiving notifications when in background mode or shut down

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problems getting my app to receive notifications while in background or shutdown mode. I have followed Firebase guide on how to implement firebase messaging in my app. Previously I have used GCM (google cloud messaging) and it all worked well, but since upgrading to Firebase I can't get it to work. As soon as I start my app, all the notifications that I sent (through firebase console notifications) while in background or shutdown are delivered.

**I have:**

- Created project on Firebase console
- Added my app to the firebase project with the correct bundle id
- Created an APNS Development certificate
- Uploaded the certificate to my app on Firebase console

Worth mentioning is that I have disabled swizzling by setting FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in my Info.plist file.

**Relevant code:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool { 
  let types: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings( forTypes: types, categories: nil )
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings( settings )
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    FIRApp.configure()
}

func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
            self.refreshToken()
        }
    }
}

func refreshToken(){
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {

        gcmToken = refreshedToken

        userDefaults.setValue(gcmToken, forKey: CONSTANTS.GCM_TOKEN)

        if(userDefaults.boolForKey("UserLoggedIn")){
            pushGcmToken() //push the token to server
        }
    }
}

func onTokenRefresh() {
    refreshToken()
    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    NSLog("didReceiveRemoteNotification \(userInfo)")

    FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    handleRemoteNotification(userInfo)

}

func handleRemoteNotification(userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
    if let notification = userInfo["notification"] as? [NSObject : AnyObject]{

        let bodyNot = notification["body"] as! String
        var titleNot = "Ändring"
        var category = "UNIFIED_OTHER_CATEGORY"
        if(notification["title"] != nil){
            titleNot = (notification["title"] as! String == "Call" ? "Inkomande samtal" : notification["title"]) as! String
            category = "UNIFIED_CALL_CATEGORY"
        }

        let notis = UILocalNotification()
        notis.alertTitle = titleNot

        notis.alertBody = bodyNot
        notis.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound
        notis.userInfo = ["UUID": "122" ] // assign a unique identifier to the notification so that we can retrieve it later
        notis.category = category
        notis.fireDate = NSDate()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notis)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    NSLog("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken \(deviceToken)")
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox)
}
```

I have even tried with swizzling on. Same thing happening. I would very much appreciate any help or hint into the right direction.

Comment: Hi, you found the answer ??

Comment: do you have whatever the firebase equivalent of `content-available = 1` on?

Answer (score 1):

I configured below things and its work fine for my application,

In info.plist set below two keys

```
<key>FIRMessagingAutoRegisterEnabledflag</key>
    <true/>
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>
```

In appdelegate set below code for test notification development mode

```
[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
```

Download **GoogleService-Info.plist** from firebase console and put it on your application

Answer (score -1):

You have to add **"content-available" : true** in the JSON payload. Otherwise you won't get push notification in the background mode.

```
"notification" : {
            "content-available" : true,
            "body" : "this is body",
            "title" : "this is title"
}
```

Comment: `content_available` should be `content-available`